# PHP foreach with Nested Array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested

I have a nested array in which I want to display a subset of results. For example, on the array below I want to loop through all the values in nested array[1].

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [0] => one
      [1] => Array
        (
          [0] => 1
          [1] => 2
          [2] => 3
        )
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
      [0] => two
      [1] => Array
        (
          [0] => 4
          [1] => 5
          [2] => 6
        )
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
      [0] => three
      [1] => Array
        (
          [0] => 7
          [1] => 8
          [2] => 9
        )
    )
)
```

I was trying to use the foreach function but I cannot seem to get this to work. This was my original syntax (though I realise it is wrong).

```
$tmpArray = array(array("one",array(1,2,3)),array("two",array(4,5,6)),array("three",array(7,8,9)));

foreach ($tmpArray[1] as $value) {
  echo $value;
}
```

I was trying to avoid a variable compare on whether the key is the same as the key I want to search, i.e.

```
foreach ($tmpArray as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == 1) {
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your intial syntax seems ok, but `$value` can be an array itself in the `foreach`. In that case you can't just echo it but you need to loop through it too.

Comment: Your [mcve] isn't crystal clear.  Maybe you want to destructure your array data with the `foreach()`? https://3v4l.org/TN52M

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you know the number of levels in nested arrays you can simply do nested loops. Like so:

```
//  Scan through outer loop
foreach ($tmpArray as $innerArray) {
    //  Check type
    if (is_array($innerArray)){
        //  Scan through inner loop
        foreach ($innerArray as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }else{
        // one, two, three
        echo $innerArray;
    }
}
```

if you do not know the depth of array you need to use recursion. See example below:

```
//  Multi-dementional Source Array
$tmpArray = array(
    array("one", array(1, 2, 3)),
    array("two", array(4, 5, 6)),
    array("three", array(
            7,
            8,
            array("four", 9, 10)
    ))
);

//  Output array
displayArrayRecursively($tmpArray);

/**
 * Recursive function to display members of array with indentation
 *
 * @param array $arr Array to process
 * @param string $indent indentation string
 */
function displayArrayRecursively($arr, $indent='') {
    if ($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                //
                displayArrayRecursively($value, $indent . '--');
            } else {
                //  Output
                echo "$indent $value \n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The code below with display only nested array with values for your specific case (3rd level only)

```
$tmpArray = array(
    array("one", array(1, 2, 3)),
    array("two", array(4, 5, 6)),
    array("three", array(7, 8, 9))
);

//  Scan through outer loop
foreach ($tmpArray as $inner) {

    //  Check type
    if (is_array($inner)) {
        //  Scan through inner loop
        foreach ($inner[1] as $value) {
           echo "$value \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may have missed my point, I only want to display a specific nested/sub array, not all of them.

Comment: @noangel sorry for misunderstanding, see revised post (the last part) after the horizontal rule. This should clarify things.

Comment: I tried your recursive array output implementation and although it works for first level, my last nested array was simply output on one line

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach ($tmpArray as $innerArray) {
    //  Check type
    if (is_array($innerArray)){
        //  Scan through inner loop
        foreach ($innerArray as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }else{
        // one, two, three
        echo $innerArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both syntaxes are correct. But the result would be `Array`. You probably want to do something like this:

```
foreach ($tmpArray[1] as $value) {
  echo $value[0];
  foreach($value[1] as $val){
    echo $val;
  }
}
```

This will print out the string "two" ($value[0]) and the integers 4, 5 and 6 from the array ($value[1]).

Comment: I only get the error: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

As I understand , all of previous answers , does not make an Array output,
In my case :
I have a model with parent-children structure (simplified code here):

```
public function parent(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Accounting\accounting_coding', 'parent_id');
}


public function children()
{

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Accounting\accounting_coding', 'parent_id');
}
```

and if you want to have all of children IDs as an Array , This approach is fine and working for me :

```
public function allChildren()
{
    $allChildren = [];
    if ($this->has_branch) {

        foreach ($this->children as $child) {

            $subChildren = $child->allChildren();

            if (count($subChildren) == 1) {
                $allChildren  [] = $subChildren[0];
            } else if (count($subChildren) > 1) {
                $allChildren += $subChildren;
            }
        }
    }
    $allChildren  [] = $this->id;//adds self Id to children Id list

    return $allChildren; 
}
```

the allChildren() returns , all of childrens as a simple Array .

Answer (score -1):

I had a nested array of values and needed to make sure that none of those values contained `&`, so I created a recursive function.

```
function escape($value)
{
    // return result for non-arrays
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        return str_replace('&', '&amp;', $value);
    }

    // here we handle arrays
    foreach ($value as $key => $item) {
        $value[$key] = escape($item);
    }
    return $value;
}

// example usage
$array = ['A' => '&', 'B' => 'Test'];
$result = escape($array);
print_r($result);

// $result: ['A' => '&amp;', 'B' => 'Test'];
```