# How to display a php 3 level array in table form

Tags: php

Currently I have a PHP 3 level array. How do I display it in a table form? Using print_r I could display out the full array but I need to beautify it to show in a table form. Is it possible?

Sample of the array to be inserted is as shown in another posting: [PHP foreach with Nested Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684463/php-foreach-with-nested-array)

Comment: This is a very simple solution. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... each level of the array should be an embedded table?

```
<table>
    <?php // FIRST LEVEL
    foreach ($myArray as $first_level): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>The header of the first level, here's some data <?php echo $first_level['some_data']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
            <?php // SECOND LEVEL
                foreach($first_level['second_level'] as $second_level): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $second_level['some_data']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

..and keep repeating the pattern

Answer (score 1):

So many ways to do it, even more so since you didn't provide a template for the output format ....
Let's assume each element `$e` of the input array `$src` stands for one row in the table.
Then $e[0] is the string element (`one`, `two`, `three`) and $e[1] is the corresponding array `1,2,3`, `4,5,6` or `7,8,9`.
Let's put $e[0] into `<th>...</th>` elements.

```
foreach( $src as $e ) {
  echo '<th>', $e[0], '</th>';
}
```

and then wrap each element in $e[1] in `<td>....</td>`.

```
foreach( $src as $e ) {
  echo '<th>', $e[0], '</th>';
  foreach($e[1] as $v) {
    echo '<td>', $v, '</td>';
  }
}
```

now wrap that into another `<tr>...</tr>` and you are done

```
foreach( $src as $e ) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th>', $e[0], '</th>';
  foreach($e[1] as $v) {
    echo '<td>', $v, '</td>';
  }
  echo "</tr>\r\n";
}
```

the same thing a bit shorter (see http://docs.php.net/join)

```
<?php
$src = getData();
foreach( $src as $e ) {
    echo '<tr><th>', $e[0], '</th><td>', join('</td><td>', $e[1]), "</td></tr>\n";
}

function getData() {
    return array(
        array( 'one', array(1,2,3) ),
        array( 'two', array(4,5,6) ),
        array( 'three', array(7,8,9) )
    );
}
```

the output is

```
<tr><th>one</th><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><th>two</th><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><th>three</th><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars