# Looping PHP Nested Arrays - Extract values into Blade Views (Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade, guzzle

I know there are many questions on this topic, but none quite deal with this (as far as I could see).

I have a PHP array (which FYI, is returned via  Guzzle response) in a Laravel Project.

**The PHP array**

```
$users = array(2) {
  ["error"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["spirits"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Foo"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "Bar"
    }
  }
}
```

I simply want to extract the "id" and "name" keys below, to use in a view but I'm a little stumped. I've tried the suggestions below, but can't quite work it out.

[How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

[PHP foreach with Nested Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684463/php-foreach-with-nested-array)

I've also looked into **array_walk_recursive**.

Any help would be awesome and appreciated! I want to be able to use these 2 keys in Laravel like so:

**Controller**

```
return View::make('users')->with('users',$users);
```

**View**

```
 @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
     {{ $user["id"] }}
     {{ $user["name"] }}
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this:

```
@foreach ($users['spirits'] as $user)
 {{ $user["id"] }}
 {{ $user["name"] }}
@endforeach
```

It's better to check the returned result in your controller before you send it to the view using something like this so there will be no errors in your view:

```
$users = 'Get it from somewhere...';
if(!$users['error']) {
    return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
}
else {
    // Show an error with a different view
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Part I was missing was `$users['spirits']`

Answer (score 1):

in case your users are always stored in the `spirits`-key of your `$users` variable you simply could modify your `@foreach`-loop as follow:

```
@foreach ($users['spirits'] as $user)
    {{ $user['id'] }}
    {{ $user['name'] }}
@endforeach
```

Otherwise you could edit your return value from the controller. That means you simply could change the line:

`return View::make('users')->with('users',$users);`

to

`return View::make('users')->with('users',$users['spirits']);`

In this case you don't have access to your `error`-key.