# passing nested array from controller to view in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I'm new to laravel and I tried to clear the problem from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299204/looping-php-nested-arrays-extract-values-into-blade-views-laravel)

I have controller like the following:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $message[] = Model::where('id',$user->id)->get();
}
$data['tests'] = $message;
return View::make('user.index', $data);
```

My View is:

```
@foreach($tests['message'] as $test)
    id : {{$test->id}}
@endforeach
```

which gives me `Undefined index: message`

I had dump the the `$data`  in the controller. my array is as shown below. I place the var_dump in the controller before the return statement. my `var_dump($data)` is showing:

```
    array(1) {
        ["tests"] => array(2) {
            [0] => object(Illuminate\ Database\ Eloquent\ Collection) #515 (1) { ["items":protected]= > array(2) {
                [0] => ["attributes": protected] => array(14) {
                    ["id"] => string(3) "12"....

        }
    }
            [1] => object(Illuminate\ Database\ Eloquent\ Collection) #515 (1) { ["items":protected]= > array(2) {
                [0] => ["attributes": protected] => array(14) {
                    ["id"] => string(3) "12"....

        }
    }
    }
```

what i'm doing wrong. please help me

Comment: Can you show your Model structure? It was depend on your model.

Comment: it consist only the table name

Comment: So, where your message come from? If key (message) not exist in your array, how you want to get with this key?

Comment: it came from the model table, obviously

Comment: Yes, that correct. Based on your code, I didn't see message key in your array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@foreach($tests as $test)
//$test is an array returned by get query.
  @foreach($test as $item)
    id : {{$item->id}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

get return array, if you want to return one element, use find() or first().

Comment: it works, Thanks @Kris Roofe... anyway, is it the correct way of passing the data, or i'm doing dump?

Comment: in your case, use the get() is the proper way prefer to first() and find().

Answer (score 2):

Your `$tests['message']` should be `$tests` because you have not define message in your controller.

```
$message = array();
foreach($users as $user){
    $message[] = Model::where('id',$user->id)->get();
}
$data['tests'] = $message;
return View::make('user.index', $data);
```

View

```
@foreach($tests as $test)
    id : {{$test->id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I have tried it.. it gives `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id `

Comment: `array(1) { ["tests"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#.... [1]=>....`

Comment: it consist `id` for sure

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$users = App\User::all()
foreach($users as $user){
    $message[] = Model::where('id',$user->id)->get();
}
$data['tests'] = $message;
return view( 'user.index', compact('data') );
```

In views/user.index.blade.php

```
@foreach($data['tests'] as $test)
    id : {{$test->id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: it gives me `undefinde property of $id`