# Creating a list (ul, li) with a php array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-lists

I have this array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 17-GUIDO HUMBERTO -3 
    [1] => 
    Array ( 
        [0] => 2-José-3 
          ) 
    [2] => 
    Array ( 
        [0] => 
            Array ( 
                [0] => 18-juan andres-3 
                  ) 
          ) 
)
```

I'm trying to put that array in a list with ul li like this:

- 17-GUIDO HUMBERTO -3

  - 2-José-3

    - 18-juan andres-3

I dont know how to do it, I do not know if the array is correct, please i need help. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP foreach with Nested Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684463/php-foreach-with-nested-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a thing called 'recursion', when you have a function that calls itself, e.g.:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    '17-GUIDO HUMBERTO -3 ', 
    array( 
        '2-José-3'
    ),
    array(
        array(
            '18-juan andres-3'
        )
    )
);


function listArr($arr) {
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $html .= listArr($item); // <<< here is the recursion
        } else {
            $html .= '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
        }
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}

echo(listArr($arr));
```