# How to access multidimensional JSON array in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a web based file manager where I can view, create, edit, and delete folders and files. 
I need a data structure for storing the information about the files folders and subfolders.

I was trying JSON, but the problem is that there can be any number of subfolders inside subfolders which will come dynamically.

I wrote by hand a JSON test file, which the link is given below

```
{
  "home": {
    "file1": {
      "type": "file",
      "name": "test",
      "ext": "pdf",
      "date": "12/03/2015"
    },
    "file2": {
      "type": "file",
      "name": "test",
      "ext": "doc",
      "date": "31/01/2010"
    },
    "folder1": {
      "type": "folder",
      "name": "folder1",
      "date": "11/01/2010",
      "in": {
        "file": {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "test3",
          "ext": "pdf",
          "date": "23/01/2017"
        },
        "folder2": {
          "type": "folder",
          "name": "folder2",
          "date": "22/03/2011",
          "in": {
            "file4": {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "test3",
              "ext": "pdf",
              "date": "23/01/2017"
            }
          }
        },
        "folder4": {
          "type": "folder",
          "name": "folder4",
          "date": "11/09/2009",
          "in": {
            "file5": {
              "type": "file:",
              "name": "file5",
              "date": "11/09/2011"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "folder7": {
      "type": "folder",
      "name": "folder7",
      "date": "23/08/2015",
      "in": {
        "file7": {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "file7",
          "date": "11/01/2016"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There will be a dynamic generation of folders and subfolders which needed to be updated in the JSON file.

How can I access all the data from the JSON file after encoding into a variable in PHP or JavaScript, and update the file with new data as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read the file using [file_open()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp)

Parse the json using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Do whatever you want with your arrays

encode the json again with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

write it to your file again with [fwrite()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp)

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
 $json = fread($myfile,filesize("json.txt"));
 $json = json_decode($json);
 //json is now an array, do whatever you want with it
 $json = json_encode($json);
 fwrite(file,json);
```

Comment: How can I access all the dimensions in json using php?

Comment: Once you use json_decode, you can work with it as an array

Comment: It would look like something like this: $json['home']['file1']['type']

Comment: How to access them if I don't know what all data is inside it and how many dimensions it went in?

home, file1, type etc are dynamically created. How to access if I cannot know the variables?

Comment: then you can just iterate the arrays using foreach, so you can access the individual indexes and keys

Comment: sure: foreach($json as $key=>$value) { echo $value; }

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. :)

Comment: One problem I am facing now is, using above code I can only go through the first layer. The file will have layers inside layers. 
And the depth is also unknown.
How can I access every layer dynamically [ I cannot know any values inside the file]

Comment: you can check if the value is an array, and if it is, iterate through it

Comment: check out this question for further reference on this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684463/php-foreach-with-nested-array

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet should work, it basically does a `json_decode($str, true)` of the JSON string :

```
$str = '{
    "type": "folder",
    "name": "folder1",
    "date": "11/01/2010",
    "in": {
        "file": {
            "type": "file",
            "name": "test3",
            "ext": "pdf",
            "date": "23/01/2017"
        },
        "folder2": {
            "type": "folder",
            "name": "folder2",
            "date": "22/03/2011",
            "in": {
                "file4": {
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "test3",
                    "ext": "pdf",
                    "date": "23/01/2017"
                }
            }
        },
        "folder4": {
            "type": "folder",
            "name": "folder4",
            "date": "11/09/2009",
            "in": {
                "file5": {
                    "type": "file:",
                    "name": "file5",
                    "date": "11/09/2011"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';


var_dump(json_decode($str, true));
```

Comment: After encoding how can I access the data from the encoded variable?

Comment: Basically, it would be something like `$array['in']['folder4']['in']['file5']['type']`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
 $json = file_get_contents('json.txt'); // read the file contains JSON code
 $array = json_decode($json); // convert json to normal php array

 //json is now a normal php array, do whatever you want with it

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($array);
 echo '</pre>';

 $json = json_encode($array);
 file_put_contents('json.txt');
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply
I'll try this